# How can i put a glyphicon in nav with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, glyphicons

I want do a nav like this:

Logo::::::::|:::::Dropdown+Search(center):::::|::::::::::Glyphcon1Glyphcon2|

---

In this moment I make this, but the glyphcon show it down of nav content.

[image: Actual nav picture]

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logotipo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <div class="input-group navbar-form navbar-center">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /btn-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></li>  
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I put the dropdown+search in the center of the nav and put the glyphcon in the same line without problems?

Comment: Can you include your CSS?

Comment: Your centered nav might be taking up the whole upper space. Use your browser tools to debug this, or set up a bin for this so we can see

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="input-group navbar-form navbar-center">` occupying the whole line so next `<div class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">` goes to right of next line. to fix that put `<div class="input-group navbar-form navbar-center">` inside other `<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">`

In element `nav navbar-nav navbar-right` you are including two icons in `<li></li>` tag which is similar like text and it goes down but when you include icon inside `<a href="#"></a>` tag a/c to bootstrap `<a>` tag it is padded inside `nav` class.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <div class="input-group navbar-form navbar-center">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /btn-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>  
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, now the glyphicon shows white and still down of the logo and the dropdawn+search.

Comment: I put that you writed and this is the result:

Comment: where is the result ?? BTW it is working.
[see here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxek5t7v/)